# Back button referrer doesn't work - Javascript nor asp.net

Tags: javascript, razor, back

I have a site that has the following framework: Page A = highest level. Page B = next Level.Page C = Lowest Level.

Page A contains 10 links the user can select that take it to a certain area of Page B (done by anchor hashes)
When you're taken to the correct anchor hash area on page B, the links that are shown are links that are part of theme Page B. Any link here takes you to a specific, unique Page C.

What I want to do is when the user clicks back (the one built in to browser, not a button on the page) or a nav tab to return to the Page B, the user is taken back to that anchored position.

The Problem:
I've tried using javascript and razor, but am getting the same issue:
If the user clicks the navigation tab to go to Page B, the referrer works and it takes the user back to the proper section of Page B.
If the user clicks the back button, the referrer does not return the Page C link and I cannot redirect the user to the proper area on Page B.

Here's the JS script:

```
 var oldURL = document.referrer;
if (oldURL.indexOf("page") !== -1 ) {
    window.location = //link with proper anchor tab
}
```

That didn't work, so tried razor (not the logic of redirect, just to see what it would return):

```
string referer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
@referer
```

Comment: Does the back button mean _'go back one page'_ or does it mean _'go up one level'_? If it's the former you can use `history.go(-1);` which is what the browser back button does. If it's the latter you can always make a link to the parent level. Trying to mix these is not a good idea, it's confuses users.

Comment: Both. The only time this instance needs to occur is when the user goes from page C to page B